# How do I grep for lines that have conditions depending on the position of characters?

Tags: regex, unix, grep

Say I have a random string of alphabets

and my goal is to match the strings that do not contain the letter 'B' before the appearance of sub-string

'PA'

ATRESFGOR**PA**HJ**B** (Valid)

AHJSF**B**SDF**PA**OPQ (Invalid)

So I figured, I would first try to match all those that did not contain letter B before appearance of 'PA'

```
grep -v '[^ ]*\B' *.txt | {condition for before 'PA'?}
```

but I could not figure out how to put it into proper format.

What can I do to satisfy the conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep '^[^B]*PA'
```

e.g.:

```
$ cat file
ATRESFGORPAHJB (Valid)
AHJSFBSDFPAOPQ (Invalid)

$ grep -E '^[^B]*PA' file
ATRESFGORPAHJB (Valid)
```